# Jenkins build failing on what looks to be the Nuget Restore step

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, nuget

I've downloaded and set up jenkins on my local machine to test it out.

I have a job created to run some basic unit tests for an automation framework. I'm stumped on this error I'm seeing. If I'm reading this message correctly it's saying that it can't find the csproj file in the listed directory but when I navigate to it manually every file is indeed there.

Did I miss a step in the job build process?

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.7.0.37604' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\NuGetScratch\m224fx2s.f0i.nugetrestore.targets(285,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\CATS Framework Unit Tests\CATS.Framework\CATS.Framework\CATS.Framework.csproj" was not found. [C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\NuGetScratch\id0uys0i.dbk.nugetinputs.targets]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command on two terminal windows, one with admin privilege and one without:

```
cd "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local"
```

The one without admin privelege won't let you. My best guess is that your process is not elevated. I would move the project to some other folder.

Comment: Just verified that I was able to navigate to that directory in both an admin / non admin command prompt without issue.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe another folder in the way is not accessible to non-elevated processes. Could you try running `dir "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\CATS Framework Unit Tests\CATS.Framework\CATS.Framework\"` on a non-admin command prompt and check if the csproj file is listed?